# Link quebrado na fila de autoavaliação do site

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, filas-de-análise

No final da fila de análise tem um link para o histórico de análises do usuário na fila:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse link deveria apontar para https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/site-eval/history?userId=[id], mas aponta para https://pt.stackoverflow.com/an%C3%A1lise/site-eval/history?userId=[id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2015.1.26.2222`